No overload matches this call for express middleware
I have created express app and created error middleware:
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { ApiError } from "../exceptions/api-error";

export default function errorMiddleware(
    err: Error  | ApiError,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) {
    if (err instanceof ApiError) {
        return res.status(err.status).json({message: err.message, errors: err.errors})
    }

    return res.status(500).json({message: "Unexpected error occurred"})
}

then use it in my app:
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import errorMiddleware from './middlewares/error-middleware';
import { ApiError } from './exceptions/api-error';



const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('Hello, Bun with TypeScript and Express!');
});

app.use(errorMiddleware)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

and for some reason faced this error
No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type '(err: Error | ApiError, req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<...>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
I have already used this logic in my prev project and its worked nicely, so why do i get error now?
What i have done wrong?

Change return res.status(... to res.status(...); return;
